# Symfony Super Roles have no access to Base Roles

Tags: php, symfony

The Super Role has no access to the inherited Roles..??

This is how my role hierarchy looks like:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:           [ROLE_BACKEND_USER, ROLE_SALES]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:     ROLE_ADMIN
    ROLE_SALES:           ROLE_USER
    ROLE_BACKEND_USER:    ROLE_USER
```

When I log in as an ADMIN I can see that the I have inherited roles "ROLE_BACKEND_USER"; "ROLE_SALES"  and "ROLE_USER".

However, I cannot access the ROLE_SALES though I have inherited the Role.

```
if(!$this->getUser()->hasRole('ROLE_SALES')) {

 throw new AccessDeniedException('Cannot loggin Need ROLE_SALES ');

}
```

Also `$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_CARMANDO')` does work..

P.S: Iam using FOS Bundle too.

Comment: Can you show how you use is_granted, so i can improve my answer ?

Comment: I use the security.authorization_checked to see if a use has certain Role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because FOSUB hasRole method checks you explicitly have the role when isGranted checks the privileges.

Currently, you have the privileges of the ROLE_SALES but not the ROLE_SALES itself. That's why isGranted works when hasRole does not

Comment: Ohh okay Thanks :)